# How to install rBLAST on RStudio?

Tags: installation

---

Hello all dear
I am new in R.
I installed R and R studio ver 3.3.4 on windows.But I can’t install rBLAST and blastSeq packages on it. I used of following two commands:

```
install.packages("rBLAST")
```

or

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("rBLAST")
```

but both showed the following erorr:

```
Warning message:
package ‘rBLAST’ is not available (for R version 3.4.3)
```

I am waiting for valuable your answer
thank you

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the rBLAST package is neither in the CRAN (explaining why your `install.packages("rBLAST")` command doesn't work), or the Bioconductor repository (explaining why the `biocLite` installation doesn't work).

You can still install it. The easiest approach is to install it directly from GitHub. This requires that the `devtools` package is installed.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("mhahsler/rBLAST")
```

The alternative is to clone or download the repository and build it yourself.

```
git clone https://github.com/mhahsler/rBLAST.git
R CMD build rBLAST
R CMD INSTALL <name of the resulting tarball>
```

Comment: I tried it out, didn't work!.. "Error: Failed to install 'rBLAST' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) installation of package '/var/folders/wh/vhz_x1f94_qccc73tn_0d_sw0000gp/T//RtmpLaq028/filebd045f3692f/rBLAST_0.99.2.tar.gz' had non-zero exit status"